# eAccelerator Issue - Cache Directory Empty

Tags: centos, cache, php

Hoping someone can give me a hand with this.

I've recently installated eAccelerator 0.9.6.1 - On a CentOS LAMP server.

Had it working fine, using the /tmp/accelerator as the cache directory.

php.ini set up:

> zend_extension="/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20060613/eaccelerator.so"
>   eaccelerator.shm_size="200"
>   eaccelerator.cache_dir="/var/cache/eaccelerator"
>   eaccelerator.enable="1"
>   eaccelerator.optimizer="1"
>   eaccelerator.check_mtime="1"
>   eaccelerator.debug="0"
>   eaccelerator.filter=""
>   eaccelerator.shm_max="0"
>   eaccelerator.shm_ttl="3600"
>   eaccelerator.shm_prune_period="180"
>   eaccelerator.shm_only="1"
>   eaccelerator.compress="1"
>   eaccelerator.compress_level="9"

php -v output:

> PHP 5.2.12 (cli) (built: Feb 3 2010
>   00:34:28) Copyright (c) 1997-2009 The
>   PHP Group Zend Engine v2.2.0,
>   Copyright (c) 1998-2009 Zend
>   Technologies with eAccelerator
>   v0.9.6.1, Copyright (c) 2004-2010
>   eAccelerator, by eAccelerator with the
>   ionCube PHP Loader v3.3.20, Copyright
>   (c) 2002-2010, by ionCube Ltd.

I had to remove the cache directory as I was testing something. Remade it, re-set permissions and found that eAccelerator was no longer creating cache files within the folder.

I thought it might be down to ownership rights on the folder so chown'd it apache.apache and this made no difference.

I recreated the directory in /var/cache instead and editted php.ini to point to the new cache dir location, chmod'd, chown'd etc. and still eAccelerator is not creating any of the cache files in the directory (just empty).

Could someone suggest what I might be doing incorrectly here. I've read through numerous pages to try and troubleshoot the issue to no avail.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

`eaccelerator.shm_only="1"` means that it won't write to the disk.